# get author_name from queried post

Tags: php, functions, loop

All I'm trying to do is, get the author name of the current post and set it's name as a tag. I tried changing author_id to author_name but didn't really get anything back.

wp_set_post_tags should return **'user_nicename' (nickname) instead of 'hey'**

Comment: If you want the `user_nicename` value, then `get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', $author_id )` would do it. And check the [reference](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) if you need help using the `get_the_author_meta` function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code lies in these three lines:

```
$queried_post = get_post($post_id);         
$author_id = $queried_post->post_author;
$first = $user_info->user_nicename;
```

You correctly get authors ID, but then you try to get some field of `user_info` variable, which is not defined anywhere in your code.

One way to fix it is to get user info (using [`get_userdata`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_userdata)) before trying to access it:

```
$author_id = $queried_post->post_author;
$user_info = get_userdata( $author_id );
$first = $user_info->user_nicename;
```

You can also use [`get_the_author_meta`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_the_author_meta/) to obtain only the field you need:

```
$author_id = $queried_post->post_author; 
$first = get_the_author_meta( 'user_nicename', $author_id );
```